# How can I create a C++ class on VSCode Automatically

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I was using Codeblocks to develop in C++ but I cannot use it anymore in my Mac because of the lack of updated versions for MacOs. I decided to start using Visual Studio Code for that.

I have the C/C++, C++ IntelliSense and Code Runner extensions installed to compile and run my program. In Codeblocks I could create a new C++ class and the IDE automatically created the .h and .cpp files with some basic code in them. Can I do something similar in vscode? Is there an extension for doing that, that you recommend?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I would actually recommend that you write all code by hand – it makes you and your muscle memory learn what the correct syntax looks and feels like and you will make fewer errors later, when you don't have your crutches around.

Comment: [This](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alexandrupana.SmartCreateCClass) extension provides similar functionality in Visual Studio. I doubt if something like that is available for VS Code.

Comment: The extension you provided is available only for Visual Studio and not for Visual Studio Code. I couldn't install it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [FleeXo.cpp-class-creator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=FleeXo.cpp-class-creator)